# How to reduce material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial end margin in android?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, material-components, android-switch

I've used **"com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial"** in that left margin having some space. How to reduce that?

I've need align straight of the everyone text. I'm not add end margin or padding of the switch, Parent layout margin only I've set. Below my XML code and styles. Please provide your suggestion to reduce that margin, Thanks.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/who_can"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            style="@style/TextBlackRegular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/video_view_result"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/who_can_view"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/video_view_result"
            style="@style/TextBlackRegular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Everyone"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_small" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
        android:id="@+id/save_switch"
        style="@style/SwitchButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/who_can"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/save_gallery"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
        app:trackTint="@color/colorSecondaryText" />
</RelativeLayout>


    <style name="SwitchButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.Switch">
            <item name="thumbTint">@drawable/switch_selector</item>
            <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_regular</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
        </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your `relativeLayout/topRelativeLayout`, You added margin. Which means you want to margin from every side. That's why It's happening

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp">
```

remove the `android:layout_margin="10dp"`. Add `margin_top`, `margin_right` what you wanna do.

Comment: I've removed that margin, Who can view my video, everyone and save to gallery all text are align to left side and right side but still switch end margin showing.

Comment: @RaJ How can I say who can view your video? You just asked for `margin`. And, how we can say that without giving us `java/kotlin` file. And, check where you added `margin_end` now. Than remove that. Then, end `margin` won't show

Answer (score 0):

You should give wrap content for switch width , or make it inside a new Relative layout

Answer (score 0):

if your end margin is showing after removing from

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp">
```

then

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
        android:id="@+id/save_switch"
        style="@style/SwitchButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/who_can"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/save_gallery"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
        app:trackTint="@color/colorSecondaryText" />
```

change in SwitchButtonStyle it gives you some default value we are happy if you share whole file

Answer (score 0):

you can see that default drawables (thumb and track) from a theme have this paddings

[image]

so the way is try to use your custom drawables (but this may affect their appearance)

```
        app:track="@drawable/track"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
```